# Helm `pre-install `hook calling to script during helm install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to use the `pre-install` hook of helm,

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md

in the docs its written that you need to use annotation which is clear but 
what is not clear how to combine it ?

```
apiVersion: ...
kind: ....
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
```

for my case I need to execute a bash script which create some env variable , where should I put this pre-hook script inside my chart that helm can use

before installation ?

I guess I need to create inside the `templates` folder a file which called: `pre-install.yaml` is it true? if yes where should I put the commands which create the env variables during the installation of the chart?

**UPDATE**
The command which I need to execute in the `pre-install` is like:

```
export DB=prod_sales 
export DOMAIN=www.test.com
export THENANT=VBAS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Helm hook launches some other Kubernetes object, most often a Job, which will launch a separate Pod.  Environment variable settings will only effect the current process and children it launches later, in the same Docker container, in the same Pod.  That is: you can't use mechanisms like Helm pre-install hooks or Kubernetes initContainers to set environment variables like this.

If you just want to set environment variables to fixed strings like you show in the question, you can [directly set that in a Pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).  If the variables are, well, variable, but you don't want to hard-code them in your Pod spec, you can also [put them in a ConfigMap and then set environment variables from that ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).  You can also use Helm templating to inject settings from install-time configuration.

```
env:
  - name: A_FIXED_VARIABLE
    value: A fixed value
  - name: SET_FROM_A_CONFIG_MAP
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: the-config-map-name
        key: someKey
  - name: SET_FROM_HELM
    value: {{ .Values.environmentValue | quote }}
```

With the specific values you're showing, the Helm values path is probably easiest.  You can run a command like

```
helm install --set db=prod_sales --set domain=www.test.com ...
```

and then have access to `.Values.db`, `.Values.domain`, *etc.* in your templates.

If the value is really truly dynamic and you can't set it any other way, you can use a Docker entrypoint script to set it at container startup time.  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921914/how-to-source-a-script-with-environment-variables-in-a-docker-build-process/55922307#55922307) I describe the generic-Docker equivalents to this, including the entrypoint script setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can take as an example the built-in helm-chart from arc* project, [here](https://github.com/richdynamix/arc/tree/master/tools/helm-chart) is the source code.
*Arc - kind of bootstraper for Laravel projects, that can Dockerize/Kubernetize existing apps written in this PHP framework.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update, I need to set them for the image in the `pre-install`, how should I do it ? I dont see it in the example you post...

Answer (score 0):

You can place ENV in POD.yaml under the template folder. That will be the easiest option.