# Dockerfile set environment variable with script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set some environment variable by a script. (Like it is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55922307)

**Dockerfile**

```
   FROM container1:latest
   WORKDIR /etc/test
   RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". env/environment.sh && command2 && command3"]
   COPY entry.sh .
   ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/test/entry.sh"]
```

**entry.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/test/env/environment.sh
exec "$@"
```

Then build the image:

```
docker build -t docker-test .
```

Then run it:

```
docker run -it -d --name env-test docker-test:latest
```

But the container stops after some seconds:

```
COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS
"/etc/test/entry.sh"   7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 1 second ago
```

Why is the container not running anymore? I would like to go into it with docker exec.
Can I somehow test if the environment variables are correctly set?

I was trying to add `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $PATH" ]` add the end, but nothing happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container exits because you don't provide it any command to run. You've set `ENTRYPOINT` to `/etc/test/entry.sh`, and that scripts tries to execute any arguments you provide (via `exec "$@"`), but you're running the image like this:

```
docker run -it -d --name env-test docker-test:latest
```

Since you're not providing a command, the container exits as soon as it starts. Adding `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $PATH" ]` isn't going to change this behavior because *that* command also exits immediately.

It's not clear what you expect this container to do.

If you just want the container to hang around for a while, you can have it run a `sleep` command:

```
docker run -it -d --name env-test docker-test:latest sleep 1800
```

Or you could bake that into the `Dockerfile` as the default command:

```
FROM container1:latest
WORKDIR /etc/test
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". env/environment.sh && command2 && command3"]
COPY entry.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/test/entry.sh"]
CMD ["sleep", "1800"]
```

But neither of these examples really makes sense; you would typically have a container run some sort of long-lived process like a web server, database, etc, rather than just hanging around as a target for `docker exec`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. Very helpful. So if I understand it correct, if CMD start a process the container should not stop running?

Comment: The container will continue running as long as the last process started by your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` does not exit or go into the background.

Comment: Thanks. In the mean time I figured out that ENTRYPOINT is only invoked by docker run. Is there a good solution to set env variables when running docker exec?