# Python throws KeyError when exporting environment variables

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a weird case where i have a secret.env file where i set all my environment variables as such:

secret.env

```
export TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY="something"
export TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET="something"
```

Then i built a docker file to export all the variables and run the app as such:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN find . -name \*.pyc -delete

# Export all variables
RUN /bin/bash -c "source secret.env";

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 8083

# run the command
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "run.py"]
```

However, this is throwing a key error:

```
$ docker run --name fortweet --rm -i -t fortweet:latest bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import socketio, app
  File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 38, in create_app
    my_settings = settings.TwitterSettings.get_instance()
  File "/app/app/setup/settings.py", line 47, in get_instance
    TwitterSettings()
  File "/app/app/setup/settings.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.consumer_key = os.environ["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'
```

When i run this on my windows, it works fine!

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597925/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-during-the-build-in-docker help? It seems that you're meant to set environment variables for a Docker session using built-in Dockerfile functionality.

Comment: You can use `docker run --env-file secret.env ...` as per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: @Karl This looks great but if i set my keys in my dockerfile and when i push it to Github, it will be visible to the public which might be an issue

Comment: `RUN source ...` will never set environment variables that last beyond the current `RUN` step; see [How to source a script with environment variables in a docker build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921914/how-to-source-a-script-with-environment-variables-in-a-docker-build-process).  For credentials that can't be included in the image, though, you'll need something like `docker run --env-file` as @jakub suggests.

Comment: @jakub thank you for this! It works just fine. If you put it as an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker run --env-file secret.env ...` to set environment variables at runtime. See the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) documentation for more info.

Sourcing a file in one `RUN` command will not persist after that `RUN` exits. You also should not store secrets in the Docker image. It is more safe to leave them out at build time and to apply them at runtime.