# Set environment variables in Docker container

Tags: docker, devops

I want to know if what I'm doing is considered best practice, or is there a better way:

#### What I want

I want to have a Docker image, which will have some environment variables predefined when run as a container. I want to do that by running some shell script that will export those variables.

#### What I'm doing

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
Dockerfile code..
..
..

RUN useradd -m develop
RUN echo ". /env.sh" >> /home/develop/.bashrc

USER develop
```

Is that a good way?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Dockerfile `ENV` directive would be much more usable than putting environment variables into a file.

```sh
ENV SOME_VARIABLE=some-value
# Do not use .bashrc at all
# Do not `RUN .` or `RUN source`
```

Most ways to use Docker don't involve running shell dotfiles like `.bashrc`.  Adding settings there won't usually have any effect.  In a Dockerfile, any environment variable settings in a `RUN` instruction will get lost at the end of that line, including files you read in using the shell `.` command (or the equivalent but non-standard `source`).

For example, given the Dockerfile you show, a `docker run` invocation like this never invokes a shell at all and never reads the `.bashrc` file:

```sh
docker run the-image env \
  | grep A_VARIABLE_FROM_THE_BASHRC
```

There are some workarounds to this ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55922307/10008173) to [How to source a script with environment variables in a docker build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921914/how-to-source-a-script-with-environment-variables-in-a-docker-build-process/55922307#55922307) describes a startup-time entrypoint wrapper) but the two best ways are to (a) restructure your application to need fewer environment variables and have sensible defaults if they're not set, and (b) use `ENV` instead of a file of environment-variable settings.

Answer (score 0):

** Check edits

Yes will probably work, if in the right order.

```
# Add user
RUN useradd -m develop

#switch to user
USER develop

#run script as user.
#RUN echo "./env.sh" >> /home/develop/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ./env.sh"
```

Although the duplicated RUN useradd is not necessary at all