# Docker Compose set env variable from command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer

I'm setting up a VSCode dev-container using [docker compose](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_use-docker-compose). I also have some file `myVersion.txt` which contains a string. I need this string inside the DockerFile while building the container, but the string has to stay inside `myVersion.txt` and I'd prefer avoiding copy-pasting it manually into another file like `.env` or `Dockerfile`.

Is there a way to achieve this? Something like `ENV MY_VERSION=${cat local/file/myVersion.txt}`, which obviously does not work

`devcontainer.json`:

```
{
  "dockerComposeFile": "./docker-compose.yml",
  "service": "game",
  "workspaceFolder": "/home/node/game",
  "remoteUser": "node",
}
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  game:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ..:/home/node/game
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /

ENV MY_VERSION=???

RUN some_command --argument $MY_VERSION
```

Comment: This sounds not unlike [Dockerfile: how to set env variable from file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642221/dockerfile-how-to-set-env-variable-from-file-contents).  You can't set `ENV` to the result of a command, but you can `RUN MY_VERSION=... some_command` within a single `RUN` instruction, or just directly do the command substitution inside the command you're running.

Comment: They are similar in flavour, but unfortunately none of the solutions really apply. The only approach that seems remotely fruitful is using `--build-arg`, but that's where the VS-Code dev container comes in. I'm not calling `docker-compose` myself, but vscode is doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you could approach it like this:

Mount the file as volume in your docket-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
    - local/file/version.txt:/version.txt
```

Then in the Dockerfile, you can `RUN some-command —version "$(cat /version.txt)"`

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it's pretty similar in spirit to what I eventually did yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

Change the context in `docker-compose.yml` to the projects root (which is here `..` as the file lies in `./.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml`)

```
  build:
    context: ..
    dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
```

and then in the `Dockerfile` one can use `COPY`:

```
COPY ./MY_VERSION.txt /MY_VERSION.txt
```